# codeigniter flow from controller to view is incorrect?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this code:

```
if(isset($result) && !empty($result))
                    {
                        if(is_string($result))
                        {

                             show_error('Failed to authenticate user with database');
                             $this->load->view('error', $result);
                        }elseif(is_object($result)){
                            show_error('ALL WENT OKAY!');
                            $this->load->view('valid', $result);
                        }
                    }
```

Now this code doesn't work as expected. Data is retrieved from database because if I do print_r($result) it will print the content which is correct. But when I have the above it doesn work. it just goes to index() method of my controller and does nothing.  Another way I tried was:

```
$this->load->view('valid', $result);
```

without any if statements. it goes to authentication page but fails to print $result because it says undefined. any idea would be helpful.

Regards

Comment: hey i have a question .. do you have an error.php file as view or the valid.php file as another view dpends on which condition is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. Pass the result like this.

```
if($result)
{
    $data['result'] =   $result;
    if(is_string($result))
    {
         show_error('Failed to authenticate user with database');
         $this->load->view('error', $data);
    }elseif(is_object($result)){
        show_error('ALL WENT OKAY!');
        $this->load->view('valid', $data);
    }
}else{
        $this->load->view('empty_view');
}
```

This should be suffecient to understand

```
$data['result'] =   $result;
$this->load->view('valid', $data);
```

Comment: Nah mate it still goes to membership/ which is my controller. the above code is written in membership/index(). SO I don't know why it is going to index() when I submit even though data is there?

Comment: it means you might be using authentication somewhere or redirect on some particular condition which is always meeting

Comment: nothing like that mate. the code flows exactly as above. So when I remove all the if statements, it works to valid.php. but that's not good because then am not checking

Comment: @sys_debug and why actually you need if condition?

Comment: as far as i see your problem if null is coming if condition is going false and not loading the view you are trying

Comment: I found out that is_string and is_object was causing an error. removed and now working on making it work.